# Can .NET 4 app call a .NET 3.5 WCF service?

Tags: wcf

About 2 years ago I worked on a WCF app, using VS 2008.  I was using BasicHttpBinding.  I got it onto a Windows 2003 Server R2, and then other projects came up, demanding attention.  Now I'm trying to get back at it, only now I want to use VS 2010 to write the client side of the app (it's going to be a WPF app).  I'm getting an error, but before I get into that I just want to know; can a .NET 4.0 app work with a WCF service written using .NET 3.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, since you are using the Basic binding, you should be able to use any version of .Net to connect to your service. BasicHttpBinding offers the most compatibility across versions, so you're on the right track.

WPF Calling WCF Using a BasicHttpBinding

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943481(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943481%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)